# Netlogo: replacing matrix elements by conditioning on other rows/columns

Tags: if-statement, matrix, netlogo

I am working in Netlogo on a series of models making heavy use matrices. Briefly, the models include a number of state-variables for different breeds, where the state-variables are often stock-like items. As a simple example, consider the model:

```
extensions [ matrix ]

globals
[
]


turtles-own 
[
  n-items
  stock-list
]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  create-turtles 2
  ask turtles
  [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set n-items 10
    let n-vars 3
    set stock-list matrix:make-constant n-items n-vars [0] ; empty matrix
    let stock-item n-values n-items [i -> i]
    let stock-cost n-values n-items [ random-normal 10 2 ]
    let stock-age n-values n-items [ random 50 ]
    matrix:set-column stock-list 0 stock-item
    matrix:set-column stock-list 1 stock-cost
    matrix:set-column stock-list 2 stock-age
  ]
 end
```

Here, each turtle's matrix `stock-list` is initialised as an empty matrix and then its columns filled in depending on the variables `stock-item` (id for stock), `stock-cost` and `stock-age`.

Imagine a `go` procedure that increments the stock age by one each time-step:

```
to go
  ask turtles
   [
     let current-age matrix:get-column stock-list 1
     let new-age map [x -> x + 1] current-age
     matrix:set-column stock-list 2 new-age
   ]
  tick
end
```

What I would like to do is an operation on `stock-cost` only if the age is greater than some value, e.g. 10

```
;; pseudo-code
for( i = 1 to I = number of items )
 {
   if ( stock-age[i] > 10 ) 
    {
      stock-cost[i] - 1
    }
 }
```

I know how to change the list of `stock-cost` conditional on its own values, using the `map` primitive, e.g.:

```
to decrease-stock-value
  ask turtles
  [
    let current-cost matrix:get-column stock-list 1
    set current-cost map [[?] -> ifelse-value (? > 10) [? - 1][?]] current-cost
    matrix:set-column stock-list 1 current-cost
  ]
```

But my efforts to generalise this to using values in a different list to condition upon have failed.

Thanks for your help! Also, any insight onto whether this is a good approach to modelling state variables such as stocks would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I think I sorted it out using:

```
to decrease-stock-value
  ask turtles
   [
     let current-cost matrix:get-column stock-list 1
     let current-age matrix:get-column stock-list 2
     let new-cost ( map [ [ a b ] -> 
        ifelse-value ( a > 10 ) [ b - 1 ] [ b ] ] 
        current-age current-cost
        )
     matrix:set-column stock-list 1 new-cost
   ]
end
```